# Create Joomla Sub Menu Module

Tags: joomla, menu, submenu, joomla3.0

Let's say in Joomla, I have a menu set up as follows:

- Menu A (alias: menu_a)

  - Sub Menu A1 (alias: submenu_a1)
  - Sub Menu A2 (alias: submenu_a2)
  - Sub Menu A3 (alias: submenu_a3)
- Menu B (alias: menu_b)

  - Sub Menu B1 (alias: submenu_b1)
  - Sub Menu B2 (alias: submenu_b2)
  - Sub Menu B3 (alias: submenu_b3)
- Menu C (alias: menu_c)

I want to set up menu modules at the footer for all the sub menus with the menu as title. It will be like as follows:

Module 1 Title: Menu A

- Sub Menu A1
- Sub Menu A2
- Sub Menu A3

Module 2 Title: Menu B

- Sub Menu B1
- Sub Menu B2
- Sub Menu B3

Is this possible?

I've tried using the usual Menu module (and RokNavMenu since I'm using RocketTheme template) but the best it can show using level limitation is as follows:

- Sub Menu A1
- Sub Menu A2
- Sub Menu A3
- Sub Menu B1
- Sub Menu B2
- Sub Menu B3

Alternatively I can simply just create a new menu and duplicate Menu A and another for Menu B but this will create a different url to reach the submenu. Say initially the url for sub menu A1's page is domain.com/menu_a/submenu_a1. But by creating duplicates, Menu A's alias will have to change and this will result in domain.com/menu_a_2/submenu_a1 for example.

So I've seen this done in a lot of website, creating something like this 'sitemap' but how actually is this done using joomla's menu module? Note that I'm using Joomla 3.0.

Comment: This looks fairly similar to a stanard RT splitmenu, which shows the sub-items for the page you're on. Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: no i do not want just sub-items for the page i'm on. i want all sub-items to be displayed at footer. kind of like a sitemap of all the pages for the website..

Comment: If you don't want to make an extension (or find an existing one), you can create *menu aliases*, that way two different menus will have the same link.

Answer (score 0):

@Marko D's solution is indeed correct. I just simple create a new menu but instead of the way I did it above, I set the menu type as 'menu item aliases' instead. This preserves the url and thus solving the issue.